# HTML5 video preview not showing in webview app

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

Need help regarding android webview HTML5 video preview.
App created successfully but not showing preview of HTML5 video format.

Video code in browser:

```
<video src="http://example.com/uploads/video/sample.mp4" class=img-responsive"></video>
```

In browser either in laptop or in mobile preview is absolutely fine but in webview apk its showing just a black box.

Edited: There was some typing error. Corrected

Comment: What is the class css details?

Comment: Is it really related to css? In browser preview image is visible but in webview app not visible.

Comment: I see that you use `sec` instead of `src`. And use the right way of the `video` tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video and what version of android do you use. https://caniuse.com/#feat=video

Comment: Typing error while posting, corrected. In mobile chrome browser video playing perfectly but not in android webview. Using Android version 5+